# How to "Auto Run" a program w/o having the admin rights?

Tags: windows, registry

In our software, user can select to make the application "Auto Run" during system startup. However, the user may not have admin rights. In this case, he won't have the rights to update the registry. I've tried both of the following paths w/o admin rights, and access is denied.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run
```

So is there any way that I can "Auto Run" a program w/o having the admin rights, regardless of the platform(Win7, Vista, XP, etc)? Thanks!

Comment: The "Startup" folder in the start menu will auto-run you. Not sure if you need rights to place a shortcut there though.

Comment: Thanks. Personally I don't like adding/removing shortcut to/from that folder, especially in the code. Besides, it probably just adds an entry in the registry underneath, which requires the rights anyway.

Comment: An entry in the Startup folder is more "user-friendly" because the user can easily see that something has been added by using the the Windows start menu. Putting something into `CurrentVersion\Run` has the smell of some "backdoor" to me (at least if the user is not explicitely asked). Only a few people will use regedit to check the registry for these kind of entries.

Comment: Well, you can write to the Start Menu in other places...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, if the user checks to auto run the program, he should know it. Whether it's kept in registry or somewhere else is rather implementation details that most users won't care about. Well, you're right. If there's other way, I'd rather not touch registry at all. Pretty hard w/ UAC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most plausible explanation for this is that your anti-virus software is blocking your attempts to write to this key. Yes it's possible that somebody has applied an ACL to that key to deny you write access but it's pretty unlikely. On the other hand it's very common for anti-virus software to take exception to programs that modify that particular key.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't require admin rights to write to HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion - the ACLs allow the current user to read and write to that key.

Comment: Not much of an answer...Perhaps this prompts us to ask how the OP is doing it? He may be doing it wrong. What method would you recommend?

Comment: I learned that mostly the keys under HKCU are OK to access w/o admin rights, but it's determined on a key-by-key basis. When I try to add an entry in HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run manually, it tells that I don't have the rights.

Comment: The default security for that key is to allow user access. Somebody must have changed the default security on that key to prevent user access. You need to figure out who changed the default security and ask them to stop.